# Hibernate unidirectional many-to-one and cascading delete

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

i am newbie in Hibernate and i need unidirectional many-to-one with on delete cascade.

Apparently the only option is, when the parent knows about its children.
But what if I do it manually via SQL? Is this solution good?

```
alter table CHILDREN 
add constraint FK_i4jjy61om foreign key (PARENT)
references PARENT
on delete cascade;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but you have to be careful to [evict](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) all Child entities belonging to the Parent you are about to delete.

If you already loaded a Parent's Child, when you delete the Parent, the Child will be deleted from the database without Hibernate knowing about the [entity state change](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-entity-state-transitions/).

To address this situation, it's better to evict all associated Child entities, to make sure you don't accidentally re-persist them through some other associations [transitive persistence](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Entity_Manager_Reference_Guide/objectstate-transitive.html).